# Jailkit/Chroot - Allow Less and More

Tags: linux, redhat, chroot, less, jailkit

I have the need to add the LESS and MORE commands to a jailed-user.  I've attempted the following and can't quite get it to work:

```
# which less;which more 

/usr/bin/less /usr/bin/more
```

Now that I know where the binaries are, I do the following:

```
jk_cp -j /usr/jail /usr/bin/less
jk_cp -j /usr/jail /usr/bin/more
```

Then when I go to test it out I get the following:

```
su - jailed-user
less err.log
```

**WARNING: terminal is not fully functional
err.log  (press RETURN)**

Not sure what else I need to do to make this fully functional

Answer (score 1):

`less` and `more` use Linux terminfo database for sending proper code combinations for your terminal you are using.

The terminfo database is located at `/usr/share/terminfo`. This has to be available inside the jail.

You don't need the whole database, only the term types that are in active use.

When logging in to the server, you can use `set` to see the value of `TERM` variable, which tells what entry the current session needs.

The termtype varies between terminal programs used to access the server.